# How can i achive glow effect as show in reference image

Tags: lighting

I want to achieve a realistic glow, as shown in the reference images, inside the lens and middle diffuser. I've tried IES light and emissionvbut it's not working

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, why IES didn't work?

Comment: IES light works for wall effect, but the central white shape isn't glowing as in the reference image. When I add emission, it appears white but lacks the desired glowing effect

Comment: You can have the glowing effect in the Compositor, have you tried?

Comment: "No, how can I try this? want to glow like bloom in evee

Comment: Thanks, buddy, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Cycles, *Bloom* is not available, but you can obtain a glow effect through the Compositor: Do a render, open the *Compositor*, enable *Use Nodes* and *Backdrop*, create an *Output > Viewer* (if you select the Viewer node you'll be able to movethe backdrop image) and an *Filter > Glare > Fog Glow*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, buddy, it is very helpful